# Hard disk corrupt twice in 24 hours

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

My Macbook Pro 13" (2011) had a Seagate 1TB hybrid drive installed as a secondary drive some 4 months ago. Yesterday the volume somehow became corrupt and unable to mount. I managed to format it using Disk Utility seemingly without any errors yesterday evening. However, this morning after recovering a few GB's of data from a backup it seems to have become corrupt and again unable to mount.

I guess my questions is: is my still relatively new drive already on the way out? Is there a command line utility I can run to perform a low-level scan for bad sectors and check its overall health?

With the hard disk crashes I've had previous to this I've never been able to format the disk again, so I guess that's why I'm finding this all a bit odd.

Edit - DriveDX is reporting a high UDMA CRC Error Count value for the drive. I did have to replace the SATA cable when I installed the drive. Could I have purchased a duff cable? If so, why would the drive work (temporarily) again after formatting?

Comment: If you can let your MBP sit for hours/days you can use DiskUtility and Erase using Security options to write zeros to disk. This will cause the disk to thrash because it'll be in constant use, and it will generate a fair amount to heat doing so, so keep the laptop in a cool room. Its a relatively simple stress test that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Buy a decent drive